# Move entire screen up when keyboard shows

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen order thread on SO on how to achieve this but solutions I have found have not really solved the issue.

when I use this :

```
<activity
        android:name=".UIComponent.ExampleClass"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeCustom"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppThemeCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

this ends up actually pusing up the screen the way I want it to, but it also wraps the screen. I don't want it to wrap the screen at all. It should move the entire screen above the keyboard without wrapping it.

How do i achieve this.

I am using this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ui_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@id/root_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#eaeaea"
                app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%" />


        </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I have this on the activities onCreate :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    callSessionExtender(getIntent(), true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wraps the screen". Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` are mutually exclusive. You need to choose the one or the other. Try each one and see if you get a behaviour that works for you in your situation.